# “You don't have the right permission to extract archives in the folder” extracting hadoop

Tags: hadoop, file-permissions, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to extract the files of hadoop to `/usr/local/hadoop`. But it shows the error

```
'You don't have the right permission to extract archives in the folder "file:" '
```

I know that's the simple permission error that are can be changed by changing configuration file but even I don't have permission to save/update files in computer. I also tried `gksudo` but still not able to extract files. Even I don't able to shift to the other drive. So hope I will get answer.

Also when I am trying to edit the configuration file then I have following error message:

```
 'You do not have the permissions necessary to save the file. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again.'
```

Means generally i want to edit or configuration files for hadoop. But i can't able to do that. How i can do that?

Comment: What commands have you tried?

Comment: I had tried command to change mode of the file like chmod 777 then file name. and lots of. But generally i want root access to all files rather than changing permission of every file when i want to modify that.

Comment: did you try doing sudo. also you need to own the files. did you try chmod

Comment: Yep. I had try the command like sudo. But it tells error that the user is not allowed for the sudo command.